# Slack api activate users.getPresence() method

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack-api

I have problem with slack api exactly every change in slack is saved in separate json file.But problem is that I want to get when user's  active/away change in json,but I can't get this information in json.I found that there is user.read scope with users.getPresence() method.Also users.info() method in user.read scope works and I have json with that information.Any ideas why one method works but another doesn't work?

Comment: Which method is failing?

Comment: @CalebNjiiri Hello I can't get json while I change status from active to away and I think users.getPresence() doesn't work,but I don't know in what exactly problem

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: @CalebNjiiri Unfortunately no. Let me explain you: Every change or message in slack is converted to json and stored in aws s3 bucket.Then using pyspark I just read those json files and get necessary information for me.Now I need info about status active/away but slack changes in active/away status does not go to aws s3 bucket.I can't find problem why there is not any json file with status changes but other changes go to s3

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the Slack Web API in place of the Slack RTM and events. What you need is to subscribe to the `presence_change` event. Ensure you subscribe to presence events for the specified users using `presence_sub`. You will be notified when a user changes the presence and from the response you can fetch and parse your json. Find more about this event [here](https://api.slack.com/events/presence_change)

Comment: Here is written ```RTM API Presence is now only available via subscription.
As of January 2018, presence_change events are not dispatched without presence subscriptions established with presence_sub. Relatedly, current user presence status is no longer communicated in rtm.start. Learn more.``` It means that I need first add all users to some list and after changes of status of those users come to s3 as json?

Comment: I have updated my answer, but to answer your question Yes you need to subscribe presence events for each user.

Comment: Sorry  but can I clarify two moments?
1.Here is presence_change event written ```Compatibility: RTM```.Will it work with slack api?
2.In presence_sub event written ```To use this event, you'll need to first connect with rtm.connect or rtm.start.``` It means first of all I must connect rtm.connect then presence_sub and then presence_change event?

Comment: 1. Look at the example here https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient you will get more context on how to user RTM and WebClient together. 2. Yes